# Prompting INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK while debugging Flash Builder 4 mobile app on real device

Tags: android, air, flash-builder, flashbuilder4, flex4.5

I am trying to build a demo application to test how can i debug or launch my android application on real device.

I have Froyo Android, OSX laptop and Flash Builder 4 IDE.

I build a very simple application, please have a look on image below:

[image]

in this when user click on "Click Me" button an email and address will be display in bottom textArea. Application is working fine on Flash Builder 4 emulator but when i try to debug application on my device, it prompt me the error below:

> Error occurred while installing the
>   application: 1580 KB/s (6108444 bytes
>   in 3.773s) pkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/Runtime.apk Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]

or when i create .apk file and try to install it on my device, Again it says me "Error in installation".

Please guide me, how can i fix that issue.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please include LogCat logs in your post. LogCat normally prints all the details about installation failures.

Comment: I found a link http://forums.adobe.com/thread/718308 . can i follow that one. I am afraid because i am new with OSX. Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Just try it and see if it helps. If not, come back here. If it worked, answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: no it is not working in my case

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error.

Check your /data/local/tmp/Runtime.apk permissions. If it is 600 as root owner, it won't install. Try changing the shell binary. Adbd Insecure worked for me. Its default writing mode is 666, and then package manager can install the apk.

-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root *.apk [Adbd Insecure]
-rw-------    1 root     root *.apk [Rom Root Shell]

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think your device is not in the certified devices category..Are you able to install AIR on your device?
You won't able to install/debug flex apps if your device is not under certified devices 
http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have HTC Wild Fire and it is not in the certified list. So i would not test my application on my phone. Is it?

Comment: @vkwave yes..you wudn't be able to.

Answer (score 1):

try to complete uninstall and then install it again. 
go to adb shell and then remove your application APK from data/data directory. and then install into device.

Comment: I was testing my app on HTC Wild fire which is not listed in adobe certified devices. Now i tested my that app on Android Tablet. It is working fine. Many thanks for you kind support.

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

Actually there is a change when creating an apk for a device or an emulator.

So adt.exe/jar is ok, you just need to provide different -target value, i.e.:

For physical device:

```
adt.bat -package -target apk -storetype pkcs12...
```

For emulator:

```
adt.bat -package -target apk-emulator -storetype pkcs12...
```

Comment: how can i provide -target? Please guide the process. Many Thanks

Comment: target mean the file that you want to convert into .apk, mostaly i placed file in sdk(folder in andoid sdk) folder for easily path setting.

Comment: i am simply using export release build functionality in Flash Builder to build my application apk. It is also creating apk file so where i will change or how for target. I am not getting that. Please guide. Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you share the sample code here, then i got the exact error that you are facing, is that feasible?

Comment: hi sir, sorry for delay. I was out of station. Please click on above link to download code zip http://www.mediafire.com/?7jxmx17v31r4y6k